# Why are some XAML effects tags in their own right and not just XML properties?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml

For example, we have:

```
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
```

Why is this not just expressed as:

```
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1" 
                Effect="DropShadowEffect" />
```

It's not a complaint, it just seems a weird inconsistency. Is there an underlying reason?

Comment: Can you have multiple border effects? That may be one reason.

Comment: @skin - that is a very good point and hadn't occurred to me. There are only two Effect values which are DropShadowEffect and BlurEffect.